# mysql full join error-#1054 - Unknown column 'feesmaster.PAIDAMOUNT' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, join

I have query which returns the data like this

```
DATE( expensemaster.`date` )    SUM( feesmaster.PAIDAMOUNT )    SUM( expensemaster.amount )
2013-01-09                         0                             7824.4
2013-01-15                         200                            211
```

please view the query,

```
SELECT DATE( expensemaster.`date` ) , 
       SUM( feesmaster.PAIDAMOUNT ) , 
       SUM( expensemaster.amount ) 
FROM 
    feesmaster
    INNER JOIN expensemaster 
        ON DATE( feesmaster.DATETIME ) = DATE( expensemaster.date ) 
WHERE 
    DATE( expensemaster.`date` ) BETWEEN  '2013-01-09' AND  '2013-01-15'
    AND DATE( feesmaster.`datetime` ) BETWEEN  '2013-01-09' AND '2013-01-15'
GROUP BY 
    DATE( feesmaster.`datetime` ), 
    DATE( expensemaster.`date` )
```

If  i replace inner to full so i can get Return rows when there is a match in one of the tables but i am getting error

**#1054 - Unknown column 'feesmaster.PAIDAMOUNT' in 'field list'**

I am using phpmyadmin.

Comment: Please reformat your question and post the structure of the tables you taks about.

Comment: What about LEFT OUTER JOIN?

Comment: @AndriusNaruševičius left outter join returns same rows as inner join

Comment: @MatteoTassinari please view now

Comment: Could you add to question your query that returns this error.

Comment: @valex "If i replace inner to full", I assume only one word changes :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I know MySQL doesn't support `FULL JOIN` so the word `FULL` in this case means an **ALIAS** for your first table `feesmaster`. So there is no column `feesmaster.PAIDAMOUNT` but `FULL.PAIDAMOUNT`.  You can implement FULL JOIN by [UNION LEFT JOIN and RIGHT JOIN](http://explainextended.com/2009/04/06/emulating-full-outer-join-in-mysql/)

**UPD:** Also in your case FULL JOIN (and LEFT/RIGHT JOIN's also) has no sense for this query as soon your WHERE conditions TRUE only if `expensemaster.date` and `feesmaster.datetime` aren't `NULL`. So only `INNER JOIN` works in this case.

Comment: can u please write in the form of query?

Answer (score 0):

Your error is an unknown column, which basically means that in `feesmaster` table there is no `PAIDAMOUNT` column (maybe a typo?).

Comment: In the example at the very beginning of the question there is an example of how the results look when INNER JOIN is used and SUM(feesmaster.PAIDAMOUNT) is in the column list.

Comment: All he does is changes from INNER to FULL, no other edits are made.