# 1054 Unknown Column in Full Join, but not other Joins

Tags: php, mysql, join

Why do I get a "1054 Unknown Column error" from the following mysql syntax:

```
SELECT attorney_first_name, attorney_last_name, att_school, att_degree_obtained
FROM jos_legalally_attorneys
FULL JOIN jos_legalally_attorney_education
ON jos_legalally_attorneys.user_id=jos_legalally_attorney_education.user_id;
```

It results in error:

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'jos_legalally_attorneys.user_id' in 'on clause'
```

I only get this error when attempting a `FULL JOIN`.  All other joins (Inner, Right, Left) are successfull when using this exact syntax. (I have tried the `FULL OUTER JOIN` variation).

Comment: You say you've tried the `FULL OUTER JOIN` variation. Did this succeed or fail?

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/

Comment: FULL OUTER JOIN failed

Answer (score 3):

Are reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14333751/mysql-full-join-error-1054-unknown-column-feesmaster-paidamount-in-field-l), MySQL does not support `FULL JOIN`, so your query is interpreted as follows:

```
SELECT attorney_first_name, attorney_last_name, att_school, att_degree_obtained
FROM jos_legalally_attorneys as FULL #FULL is taken as table alias!!
INNER JOIN jos_legalally_attorney_education
ON jos_legalally_attorneys.user_id=jos_legalally_attorney_education.user_id;
```

Now, since it has `FULL` as table alias for `jos_legalally_attorneys`, it doesn't work properly.

If you try the following query, it should give no error (even though it doesn't do what you want):

```
SELECT attorney_first_name, attorney_last_name, att_school, att_degree_obtained
FROM jos_legalally_attorneys
FULL JOIN jos_legalally_attorney_education
ON FULL.user_id=jos_legalally_attorney_education.user_id;
```

Now, in order to get the `FULL JOIN` you need under MySQL, you need to do something like this (as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7978663/mysql-full-join)):

```
SELECT attorney_first_name, attorney_last_name, att_school, att_degree_obtained
FROM jos_legalally_attorneys
LEFT JOIN jos_legalally_attorney_education
ON jos_legalally_attorneys.user_id=jos_legalally_attorney_education.user_id
UNION ALL
SELECT attorney_first_name, attorney_last_name, att_school, att_degree_obtained
FROM jos_legalally_attorneys
RIGHT JOIN jos_legalally_attorney_education
ON jos_legalally_attorneys.user_id=jos_legalally_attorney_education.user_id
```

Comment: Clami219, thank you for the detailed response.  The recommended syntax yielded the same error code.  I'm scratching my head on this one.