# FULL JOIN query results in Error Code: 1054. Any workaround?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, outer-join

I'm trying to join two tables to show all rows that match the where clause, not just the ones that match the join. It's two tables of bills and I am trying to merge them so that each row with matching year and month from both tables has a few fields from each.

```
SELECT
    tblhydrobill.billyear, tblhydrobill.billmonth, tblhydrobill.KWH as elecconsumption, tblhydrobill.CurrentCharges as eleccost,
    tblgasdata.cubicft as gasconsumption, tblgasdata.total as gascost
FROM tblhydrobill
FULL JOIN tblgasdata ON tblhydrobill.billyear = tblgasdata.billyear and tblhydrobill.billmonth = tblgasdata.billmonth
WHERE tblhydrobill.meteridnumber = 19 and tblgasdata.buildingid = 19
ORDER BY tblhydrobill.billyear asc, tblhydrobill.billmonth asc
```

LEFT JOIN executes properly, but only shows results where data exists for month/year on both tables. I am trying to get it to return all rows, it's ok if there are null fields on one side of the join if there is no match on the other side and vice-versa.

Using FULL JOIN I get the following MySQL error:

```
Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'tblhydrobill.billyear' in 'field list'
```

Update:

FULL JOIN is not supported yet by MySQL as pointed out by @jarlh, thanks.

Comment: AFAIK MySQL has no FULL OUTER JOIN support.

Comment: Also, your WHERE clause conditions make the FULL JOIN return regular INNER JOIN result. Move those conditions to the ON clause to get true FULL JOIN result. (On a dbms supporting it.)

Comment: Also note that tables have _columns_, not fields.

Comment: Posting the full error message would help.

Comment: As MySQL does't recognize `FULL  JOIN` , 'FULL' is most probably interpreted as an alias of `tblhydrobill`. So `tblhydrobill.billyear` is not valid col reference anymore.

Comment: @jarlh I saw FULL referenced here: https://mysqlcode.com/mysql-full-join/ but looking at mysql.com v8 ref. guide, no mention of it! The error referred to the column as a field, perhaps field is what they call a column when written in a select statement.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [1054 Unknown Column in Full Join, but not other Joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26614500/1054-unknown-column-in-full-join-but-not-other-joins)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate a list of year-month pairs that are present in one or both tables using `union`, then left join the two tables with that result:

```
select *
from (
    select billyear, billmonth from tblhydrobill where meteridnumber = 19
    union
    select billyear, billmonth from tblgasdata   where buildingid = 19
) as ym
left join tblhydrobill on tblhydrobill.billyear = ym.billyear and tblhydrobill.billmonth = ym.billmonth and tblhydrobill.meteridnumber = 19
left join tblgasdata   on tblgasdata.billyear   = ym.billyear and tblgasdata.billmonth   = ym.billmonth and tblgasdata.buildingid = 19
order by ym.billyear, ym.billmonth
```

Note that it is possible to build `ym` list manually e.g.:

```
from (
    select 2022,  1 union
    select 2021, 12 union
    select 2021, 11
) as ym
```

Answer (score 2):

Since MySql doesn't support `FULL JOIN`, it's using `FULL` as the alias for tblhydrobill.

But a FULL JOIN can be emulated.

```
SELECT h.billyear, h.billmonth
, h.KWH as elecconsumption
, h.CurrentCharges as eleccost
, g.cubicft as gasconsumption
, g.total as gascost
FROM tblhydrobill h
LEFT JOIN tblgasdata g 
  ON g.billyear = h.billyear 
 AND g.billmonth = h.billmonth
 AND g.buildingid = 19
WHERE h.meteridnumber = 19

UNION ALL

SELECT g.billyear, g.billmonth
, h.KWH as elecconsumption
, h.CurrentCharges as eleccost
, g.cubicft as gasconsumption
, g.total as gascost
FROM tblgasdata g 
LEFT JOIN tblhydrobill h
  ON h.billyear = g.billyear 
 AND h.billmonth = g.billmonth
 AND h.meteridnumber = 19
WHERE g.buildingid = 19
  AND h.billyear IS NULL

ORDER BY billyear, billmonth
```

Comment: UNION ALL will collapse non-matching doubles in left/right table as well. Use this method with caution, it can return results a bit different from FULL JOIN.

Comment: `UNION ALL` doesn't make duplicate rows unique though. And the 2nd suery is merely adding what's missing in the first. I still prefere it over using the normal `UNION` for this.

Comment: Consider [the example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8e1b631d5c620cd3638731f3ca23ccb1). Note both UNION and UNION ALL are different from FULL JOIN

Comment: @Serg See [this version](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=3bafb3c4d3b101a806c15ebae0da530c) of your fiddle. Notice the `where t1.id is null`.

Comment: Good. It works as expected.

Comment: Btw, a postgresql version with a working full join to compare : *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=edaa5a99aa1a03705c1fcb4bff3b7c02)*